# Get-History inside a powershell script file

Tags: powershell

I want to know the last executed command inside of my powershell script file.

For example my script file looks like

```
echo "hello"
$x=(Get-History)[-1]
echo $x
```

In real I am having a much larger script file

This should output me " echo 'hello' ". But it outputs me the last command executed in powershell terminal.

Is there a way to get last executed command inside a powershell script file.
I actully want to use the StartExecutionTime property of the history.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell does not natively support this, but if you need to trace out a number of commands to see which is the slowest in a script, you could use a construct like this one:

```
$commands = @(
    'write-host 123',
    'write-host 234',
    'set-location c:\git',
    'write-host 123',
    'set-location c:\temp'    
)

forEach ($c in $commands){
    $stopWatch = Measure-command -Expression {Invoke-Expression $c}
    Write-host "The last command [$c] was executed in [$($stopWatch.TotalMilliseconds)]"
}
```

This will execute all of commands within the array `$commands` one by one and run `Measure-Command` on them, which returns a rich `TimeSpan` object that has the `TotalMilliseconds` field you were looking to use.  Outputs like this:

```
The last command [write-host 123] was executed in [2.3979]
The last command [write-host 234] was executed in [0.031]
The last command [set-location c:\git] was executed in [0.0236]
The last command [write-host 123] was executed in [0.021]
The last command [set-location c:\temp] was executed in [0.0171]
```

The snippet of code could be modified to work with a script too, so if we imagine we had a script like this:

```
#myCoolScript.ps1
write-host 123
start-sleep -Seconds 2
write-host 234
start-sleep -Seconds 1
set-location c:\git
write-host 123
set-location c:\temp
```

You could modify the code like so to measure out each line:

```
$commands = get-content .\MyCoolScript.ps1
forEach ($c in $commands){
    $stopWatch = Measure-command -Expression {invoke-expression $c}
    Write-host "The last command [$c] was executed in [$($stopWatch.TotalMilliseconds)]"
}
```

Which would give this output:

```
The last command [write-host 123] was executed in [10.1866]
The last command [start-sleep -Seconds 2] was executed in [2000.178]
The last command [write-host 234] was executed in [1.1301]
The last command [start-sleep -Seconds 1] was executed in [999.5883]
The last command [set-location c:\git] was executed in [0.5302]
The last command [write-host 123] was executed in [0.9388]
The last command [set-location c:\temp    ] was executed in [0.3985]
```

Comment: Very cool trick to read out execution time for a series of commands. Thx

Answer (score 0):

`Get-History` shows the command history of your interactive PowerShell session from PSReadLine. But when you execute it as a script you won't see this.

If you want to get the last run command in a script you should be able to use the automatic variable `$$` which will show the result of the last command.

There is also the `Get-PSCallStack` which is used for debugging that shows the call stack in your running session.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.  The "hello" is first:

```
PS C:\Users\admin\foo> .\test
hello

  Id CommandLine
  -- -----------
   3 emacs test.ps1
```

StartExecutionTime:

```
PS C:\Users\admin\foo> (get-history)[-1] | % startexecutiontime

Thursday, June 4, 2020 10:26:14 AM
```

Are you saying you want the start time of the echo?

```
$a = get-date
echo "hello"
$a

Thursday, June 4, 2020 10:30:19 AM
```